# How to implement Recaptcha V3 for Kentico?

Tags: kentico, recaptcha-v3

We are going to apply the Recaptcha V3 for our sites. But Kentico is supporting the V2 only.

So are there any documents or guides to do it?

Or should we keep using the V2?

Thanks,
Duc Huynh

Comment: Which version of Kentico are you using?

Comment: our websites are running with Kentico 10,11,12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Steps:

1. Create a Class > Function for Validate ReCaptcha - see attached code;
2. Call the Function Validate in this Event: viewBiz_OnBeforeSave once submitting a form;
3. If Valid then Store the info

You can use it via Ajax or Submit Directly.

```
public static GooogleRecaptchaResponse ValidateGgRecaptchaToken(string responseToken, Action InvalidHandler) {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(responseToken)) {
        EventLogProvider.LogInformation("ValidateGgRecaptchaToken", "Invalid", "Recaptcha was empty");
        InvalidHandler?.Invoke();
        return null;
    }
    string secretKey = SettingsKeyInfoProvider.GetValue(WebUtils.CaptchaSecretKeyName);
    var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify");

    var postData = "response=" + responseToken;
    postData += "&secret=" + secretKey;
    var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.ContentLength = data.Length;

    using(var stream = request.GetRequestStream()) {
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }

    var response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();

    var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
    var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject < GooogleRecaptchaResponse > (responseString);
    if (res == null || !res.success || res.score < 0.5) {
        EventLogProvider.LogInformation("ValidateGgRecaptchaToken", "Invalid", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(res));
        InvalidHandler?.Invoke();
    }

    return res;
}
```

Comment: @stuzzo see here

Comment: Thank you for you response. Now, I will come back on this task. The event that you call viewBiz_OnBeforeSave that's CMS.OnlineForms.BizFormItemEvents.Insert.Before?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it by building a custom code to render the V3 Captcha.

Then I will check the reCaptcha Code before save the form.

Comment: Hi, do you have posted your solution somewhere? Thank you.

Comment: @stuzzo you need to create a custom code to check the RecaptCha 3 Validate before Saving the Form Data. Do you want me to send you the step by step?

Comment: Yes, it'll be appreciated. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @stuzzo see the new Answer for detail

Comment: Thanks Duc for your help!